# JAX-RS Get Open Connection Time

Tags: http, tcp, jax-rs

I'm using JAX-RS to make HTTP request.  Is there a way to get the time that it takes to open a connection (as apposed to the time to get a response after the connection is already opened)?

The opening of the connection and reading the response seem to be hidden from the calling function.

Comment: It's not very clear what you mean.  On the server side or the client side (I believe you mean client)?  How do you expect to separate what is O/S overhead with Java overhead?  What about the network overhead (i.e. how fast of a network are you measuring)?

Comment: Correct, I am looking for client side times.  

JAX-RS has a configuration for connection timeout as well as read timeout.  Is there a way to tell if the connection is timing out or if the read is timing out?

I'd be fine with a measurement from the OS or Java.  A solution that uses netstat or other system resource would be good enough.